# Include local library in editing mode into environment.yml

Tags: python, conda, devops, setuptools

I am currently building a library and facing the issue of finding a way to share the project path across all submodules.
To solve this, I was suggested to install the library in **editing mode** using `pip install -e .` at `project_root/` where `library` (module) and `setup.py` are stored.

Thanks to this, inside `library/subfolder1/script.py` I can write:

> from library.subfolder2 import fun
>
> fun()

And keep on writing the library.

This library is a project and to prevent other contributors from having to do the hackish `pip install -e .`, I was wondering if there is a way to add the library in its requirements in the `environment.yml` in editing mode.

The `environment.yml` is used to create a `conda env` and I know that `pip` dependencies can be added to it, I just do not know if options and local files (relative to `project_root/`) modules can be specified.

Many thanks in advance to anyone reaching this point.

Comment: That might be useful: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-develop.html

Answer (score 2):

In **environment.yml** add this to the dependencies section:

```
dependencies:
  - pip
  - pip:
    - --editable <path to library>
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to specify the path. The structure is the following: e.g. `/Users/login/project_root/library`

Comment: What I meant was : how to specify the path de relatively to the .yml file. 

Anyway I found the solution adding to the pip dependencies " -e ../ " so "-e" instead of the "--editable" and the path to "setup.py". Even if it was not the full answer to my problem, thank you for your answer.

Comment: That should be asked as a separate question actually.